# Chinese characters not showing in iText7 using custom font

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am using C# and iText 7.2.1.

I have a font file **SourceHanSerifCN-Light.otf** and the following test code:

```
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;

namespace iTextTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter("test.pdf");
            var pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var doc = new Document(pdfdoc);
            var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("SourceHanSerifCN-Light.otf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);
            var p = new Paragraph().Add("ABCD甲乙丙丁1234").SetFont(font);
            doc.Add(p);
            doc.Close();
            pdfdoc.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is like this. Only ASCII characters are visible. What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked, the font  is created? Put a breakpoint in your code - may be it just can't find the file.

Comment: Looking at the text, it does not use a `SERIF` font!

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks. I checked the font file and found it may be problematic because other fonts are OK.